# Python - can't run a .py from Terminal on mac because it has a space in the file path?

Tags: python, macos, terminal

I'll run something like
`python /Users/username/Google Drive/Python/Production_Code/script.py`

but will get "Invalid Syntax" with an arrow pointing to the space between "Google" and "Drive". If I put quotes (single or double) I get a syntax error pointing at the quotes. Any advice? Just want to run a script from Terminal!

Comment: Quotes (either single or double) should work. What is the exact command you tried, and what's the exact error you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a backslash after Google:

```
python /Users/username/Google\ Drive/Python/Production_Code/script.py
```

You could also Press `Tab` key after typing Google and it will enter it automatically.

Comment: Thanks Pavneet, that worked! Just curious, is it always this annoying to run file paths with spaces? I would think right click -> copy as pathname on a .py file should get me the right input for Terminal, but clearly that's not the case.

Comment: @Anikumar Copy as Pathname gives you a raw pathname, not one encoded (quoted/escaped) for shell consumption (pasting into a shell command line is just one of the many things you might want to do with a pathname, and adding shell quotes/escapes would generally make it fail for any other purpose). BTW, another option is to drag-and-drop a file from the Finder into a Terminal window -- that *does* add escapes suitable for shell consumption.